# how to make an echo bot that turns on on command and turns off when user say stop | discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need the bot to start repeating the user's messages after the `k!echo` command until he says `stop`
I tried using `bot.wait_for()` but it didn't work

code:

```
async def echo(ctx, *args):
    channel = ctx.channel
    def check(m):
        return m.content == ctx.content and m.channel == channel
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await ctx.send(ctx.content)
```

error:

```
    return m.content == ctx.content and m.channel == channel
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Comment: The error is clear: 'Context' object has no attribute 'content'. Check the documentation for the [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#context) object.

Answer (score 1):

I coded my solution with bot.tree.command so you need to convert it to ctx command.

```
boolean = False
@bot.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    global boolean
    if boolean:
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if message.content == "k!echo":
            boolean = False
            return
        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.TextChannel):
            await message.channel.send(message.content)
    else:
        pass

@bot.tree.command(name="echo")
async def echo(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    global boolean
    boolean = True
    channel = interaction.channel
    await interaction.response.send_message('Bot will start echoing. Type "k!echo" to stop.')
    async def check_stop(msg):
        return msg.content == "k!echo" and msg.author.id == interaction.user.id
    try:
        while True:
            response = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check_stop, timeout=60.0)
            await channel.send(response.content)
            break
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await interaction.response.send_message('Echoing stopped due to inactivity.')
```

So what I did here?

- made a global variable named boolean (cause I'm so creative) which is a boolean
- the `on_message` needs this boolean to be True to start, the boolean's default value is False and by using the echo command, you set it to True
- if you type k!echo, the boolean is set to False again.
- added a timeout handler

Comment: To enable multiple users to use the command, I recommend that you use an `echo_user_ids` list that will contain the ids of the users who have the command active. So, in the `on_message` event you can check if the author is in the list.
And in the `echo` command, you will add and remove users from this list.

Comment: The bot does not work together with this code, as does the `echo` command and the rest of the commands. Other teams function without it. There are no errors in the console

Comment: @kot_v_palto You need to convert the `bot.tree.command` to a `bot.command()` and if your other codes does not work  you need `await bot.process_commands(message)`  in the `on_message` function. Plus make sure you never defined `on_message` before.

Comment: @Rexy idk why, `@bot.tree.command()` returns an error `AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'tree'`

Comment: it is because you have bot defined not as `commands.Bot`. But what I'm saying is that you can't just copy this code, cause it wont work. You need to rewrite it using `bot.command()` and going through the same logic.